# how to use update statement using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to show up an error when there is no results upon updating an `statement` so i've tried using this code with none existed `ID`.

But this code is always giving me `success`! however i'm trying to test it with wrong `id` that not exist! can you show me what is wrong with this code.

```
<?PHP
include("config.php"); // For connection

$product_name = '52 inch TV';
$product_code = '9879798';
$find_id = 188; // id not exist should gives Error

$statement = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE products SET product_name=?, product_code=? WHERE ID=?");
$statement->bind_param('ssi', $product_name, $product_code, $find_id);
$results =  $statement->execute();

if($results){
    print 'Success! record updated';
}else{
    print 'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code

```
if($statement->affected_rows > 0){
    print 'Success! record updated';
}else{
    print 'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqli_affected_rows` after `$results =  $statement->execute();`. This will give you the count of updated rows. So you can check accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The probelm with your current logic is that the query you issue does not generate an error it just does not update any rows.

If you want to ensure an error try making the query so it wont compile at all.

Also as these statement return objects OR `false` it is better to test specifically for `false` using the `===` rather than a `if($var)`

```
<?php
include("config.php"); // For connection

$product_name = '52 inch TV';
$product_code = '9879798';
$find_id = 188; // id not exist should gives Error

$statement = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE products 
                                  SET product_name=?, 
                                      product_code = ? 
                                WHERE IDXX = ?");    // <-- generate error

$statement->bind_param('ssi', $product_name, $product_code, $find_id);
$results =  $statement->execute();

if($results === false){
    print 'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
}else{
    print 'Success! record updated';
}
?>
```

Otherwise if you actually want to know if the query actually amended something you must check for the affected row count

```
<?php
include("config.php"); // For connection

$product_name = '52 inch TV';
$product_code = '9879798';
$find_id = 188; // id not exist should gives Error

$statement = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE products 
                                  SET product_name=?, 
                                      product_code = ? 
                                WHERE ID = ?");

$statement->bind_param('ssi', $product_name, $product_code, $find_id);
$results =  $statement->execute();


if($results === false){
    print 'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
}else{
    print 'Success! record updated';
    echo sprintf('Query changed %d rows', $mysqli->affected_rows);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I typically do is something like this.

Also, you need to make sure you have a field or something that is unique to this record. Basically, it will always INSERT the way it's written, since we're just checking one value (birthday)

Here's an example
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'pwd', 'db');

```
        // check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
        }          
                // check to see if the value you are entering is already there      
                $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM birthday WHERE name='Joe'");
                if ($result->num_rows > 0){ 
                    // this person already has a b-day saved, update it
                    $conn->query("UPDATE birthday SET birthday = '$birthday' WHERE name = 'Joe'");
                }else{
                    // this person is not in the DB, create a new ecord
                    $conn->query("INSERT INTO `birthday` (`birthday`,`name`) VALUES ('$birthday','Joe')");
                }
```

Check the additional example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)